# From whole number to percentage in SQL extract in Power BI

Tags: sql, type-conversion, powerbi, percentage, sqldatatypes

I have to extract data in Power BI using a SQL statement. It is a simple `select ... from ... group by ...` and then I retrieve for example the value 925. And here is my request. What I want is to retrieve 9,25 directly with the SQL statement but I can't find how. When I use a `Cast` or `Convert` I always retrieve 9 without the decimals. And if I use the Data Type "percentage" from the Query Editor it will display 925000 so this is not the solution.

Any idea ?

Comment: So you're getting 925, but you actually want 1/100th of that? Why not just divide/multiply in the original query or divide/multiply in Query Editor?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple query pattern like that, I would not bother with a custom SQL statement. Just connect to the source table/view using the Navigation UI, then add a Group By step in the Query Editor window.

You will have less code to maintain (actually none), and the underlying datatypes will be passed through automatically.